# Powershell 4 compatibility with Windows 2008 r2

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

In my environment I have a single server that has access to pretty much my entire network.  That server is running Windows 2008 r2, and I have upgraded Powershell to version 4.0.  The question I have is this...  Can I run cmdlets from that machine on other machines that are version 4 specific?

For instance, when I am using Powershell, even though it is version 4, it doesn't give me an intellisense autocomplete for "Get-Volume" like it would on a 2012 r2 machine.  I understand that it won't run on that machine because the infrastructure won't allow for it, but what about a 2012 r2 machine remotely?

I am looking to run batch scripts from there for various purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is probably a ServerFault-question as it's related to server-administration.

PowerShell 4.0 installed on 2008 R2 can't run 2012 cmdlets on a 2012 R2-machine like `Get-Volume -ComputerName My2012Server`, because the cmdlets doesn't exist on your 2008 R2 machine. However, you should be able to invoke the cmdlet on the 2012 R2-server, like:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName My2012Server -Scriptblock { Get-Volume }
```

Be aware that you would not get autocomplete support when writing it as the commands and help files aren't installed on your 2008 R2-server

[`Import-PSSession`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849970.aspx) is also a possibility if your gonna run the commands interactively. For a script I would probably still use `Invoke-Command`.

Answer (score 2):

Get-Volume in your example is available only on Windows Server 2012 and above. So, it won't auto-complete on a 2008 R2 system. You can use PowerShell [implict remoting](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1151).

Using implict remoting, you can import all cmdlets from a remote system into a local session and use them as if they are available on the local system.